# footer disappear when overflow:auto is applied to content "above" it

Tags: html, css

I imagine this to be a simple question to answer for people experienced in HTML & CSS, but I have searched Google and StackOverflow for an answer, can't seem to find it.

I have an image gallery that in mobile devices (width < x) shows an image gallery in vertical alignment where the user scrolls through image gallery vertically. The CSS overflow: auto is applied to imageGallery when deviceWidth < x.

I have a footer that I want to be sticky to bottom of the page. The image gallery should be scrollable "behind" the footer, while the footer should still be visible. The overflow: auto when applied to image gallery makes the footer disappear even when position: fixed or absolute or relative is applied to footer. Do you have a solution to this problem?

Thank you in advance!

The HTML in question:

```
<section id="gallerySection">
<!--images  in this section-->
</section>

<footer>
<!--footer comes after the imageGallery in HTML layout-->
</footer>
```

The CSS:

```
body{
background-color: black;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
width: 100;
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}

*{
box-sizing: border-box;
}

#gallerySection{
width: 70%;
height: 70%;
position: absolute;
top: 15%;
left: 15%;
background-color: black;
z-index: -1;
margin: 0px;
}

//the images in gallery are shown vertically as block objects when screen
//width is low. When deviceWidth is > than this there is a different
//code for imageGallery entirely that works fine.
@media screen and (max-width: 580px){
#gallerySection{
    height: 60%;
    overflow: auto; 
}
}

footer{
background-color: gray;
width: 70%;
height: 15%;
min-height: 15%;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0px;
left:15%;
margin: 0px;
z-index: 1;

}
```

Comment: have you tried overflow-y: auto; overflow-x:hidden;